Diaconis' argument for 3 shuffles in a deck
I remember hearing that the great probabilist Persi Diaconis had said that three shuffles of a deck suffice to give an adequately shuffled deck. I wonder if there is an original reference to this claim, and or if there are convincing criteria or assumptions to prove the claim.

+1 but I wonder if this is a matter of the mathematics of probability or the psychology of watching a deck of cards being shuffled.

It depends on how one characterizes a "shuffle."  Evidently it's not just any permutation, but what subset of permutations would it be?  A perfect shuffle, in which half of the cards are interleaved with the other half?  Or could it be more general, comprising the permutations often achieved by less-skilled card handlers?

Quickly googling leads to this paper - https://escholarship.org/content/qt0k4654kx/qt0k4654kx_noSplash_917db55c6dcd57c447e71c449cc74676.pdf which is quite dense and formal. It doesn't seem that 3 is explicitly mentioned, but the formal details seem to be there albeit quite dense. I guess a worthwhile answer could spell the details in a digestable upshot - which I can attempt given sufficient time.

More compelling is the paper "The Mathematics of Perfect Shuffle" collaboration with Graham of Bell fame.

I don't recall Diaconis saying "three"; I do seem to recall an occasion where he mentions a larger number, I think perhaps it was seven. That would have been for riffle shuffles.

The paper AdamO links has a part which is pretty explicit about 3 or 4 shuffles (with cuts in between) not really being adequate (being exploitable), and cites a number of papers that suggest that at least 7 (imperfect) riffle shuffles may be needed. Some larger numbers are mentioned in the paper in some sections.
